# These sequences must somewhere stop (in the sense of primality) , right?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose that we take some prime $p$ and form a sequence:

$$a_1=p,$$

$$a_2=2p+1,$$

$$a_3=2(2p+1)+1=4p+3,$$

$$\ldots$$

$$a_n=2^{n-1}p+2^{n-1}-1.$$

There is no prime $p$ for which this sequence consists only of primes, right?

What is the longest "run" of primes that you can find?

Comment: Hint:  $2^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Comment: How much checking have you done?

Comment: @lulu (+1) Not if $p=2$ :-p

Comment: @ArnaudMortier  True. Should have said "for odd primes $p$".

Comment: @EthanBolker Not much.

Comment: When you ask a casual question you haven't thought about yourself you entice people here to spend and perhaps waste time on something that might be false or obvious or boring. Please don't do that.

Comment: @EthanBolker Somebody maybe likes to seek for long runs.

Comment: lulu has already explained why there won't be any long runs. Case closed.

Comment: To complete lulu's explanation, the case $p = 2$ has to be considered.

Comment: Also note that unless $p \equiv -1 \pmod{10}$, the sequence very quickly reaches a composite multiple of 5.

Answer (score 4):

As @lulu points out, when $p \ge 3$, $\gcd(2,p) = 1$, so by Fermat's Little Theorem,
$$a_p=2^{p-1}p+2^{p-1}-1$$
is a multiple of the prime number $p$.

To address the case $p = 2$, raised by @ArnaudMortier, by inspection,
$$a_6=2^{6-1}(2)+2^{6-1}-1 = 64 + 32 - 1 = 95 = 5 \times 19,$$
so $(a_n)_n$ must contain composite numbers.